# how to avoid static_cast when using std::make_tuple with overloaded functions

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

g++ says

> error: too many arguments to function 'constexpr std::tuple

if I leave out the static_cast in the `std::make_tuple` call

```cpp
#include <tuple>

typedef int (*func_t)();

int number() {
  return 2;
}

double number(bool a) {
  return 1.2;
}

int main() {
  // With a static_cast it compiles without any error
  // std::tuple<func_t> tup = std::make_tuple(static_cast<func_t>(number));                                                               

  std::tuple<func_t> tup = std::make_tuple(number);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is full error message:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cc
test.cc: In function 'int main()':
test.cc:31:54: error: too many arguments to function 'constexpr std::tuple<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type ...> std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {}; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type = <type error>]'
In file included from test.cc:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tuple:844:5: note: declared here
test.cc:31:54: error: conversion from 'std::tuple<>' to non-scalar type 'std::tuple<int (*)()>' requested
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If I change the main function to

```cpp
int main() {
  std::tuple<func_t> tup = std::make_tuple(static_cast<func_t>(number));                                                               
  return 0;
}
```

the program compiles just fine. Is it possible to leave out the static_cast somehow? It seems unnecessary to provide the type **func_t** two times.

Comment: Try std::make_tuple<func_t>()

Comment: How do you think, what function `int number()` or `double number(bool a)` should be passed to `std::make_tuple(number);` ? You can try like this: `std::tuple<func_t> tup( (number) );`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `std::make_tuple`. Use *braced-init-list* as:

```
std::tuple<func_t> tup { number };
```

Now the compiler will select the appropriate overload matching `func_t`.

See [live demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2188ab7dff57069cd38e2445c0702a13)

Comment: Can you remove the 'live demo' link.

Comment: Is it just an example of where to test code? Not sure what the link is for.